# Hide extra items from sharedmenucontroller in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to display UIMenuController in UIWebView, it displays correctly, but shows default items. I tried to remove it by forbidding actions in canPerformAction, but it still does not work, although this method is being called by UIMenuController

This is MyWebView which is a subclass of UIWebView

```
@implementation MyWebView

- (void) displayMenu: (NSString *) word atX: (int) x atY: (int) y {
[self becomeFirstResponder];
 UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake(x, y, 0, 0);
[menuCont setTargetRect:selectionRect inView:self];
menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowUp;
menuCont.menuItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return YES; }
```

I disabled every action, by returning NO from canPerformAction, but still it shows them.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@" Can perform action? %@ %s", sender, sel_getName(action));
    return NO;
}
```

Here is what I see :

[image]

Any ideas how to remove these default actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think figured it out.

I had another

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}
```

In my view controller, after I removed it, it started to work correctly, although it is still unclear why this was an issue, since this method returned NO anyway.